# Trivial question about a double summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say I have a function $f$ defined in $\{1,2,...,n\}\times \{1,2,...,m\}$ by $f(i,j)=ij$, is it immediately obvious that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m f(i,j)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m ij
\end{equation}
or does it require some kind of proof? I'm seriously asking because this has been bothering me.

Comment: Immediately obvious. No proof needed. Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you
know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible
answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered
the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent
people from telling you things you already know, and help them write
their answers at an appropriate level.

Comment: Well instead of $ij$ it was $a_ij c_j y_i$ where the $a_ij's$ come from a matrix, the $c_j's$ are the coordinates of a vector with respect to some basis and the $y_i's$ are vectors (i.e. this was from a linear algebra book). The problem is that I get obsessed over this kind of trivialities, how do I get over them?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. $f(i,j)$ is defined to be $ij$, so what is there that needs to be proved?

Comment: @JLA nothing, as I said in my other thread, I'm just obsessed.

Comment: @user121566 If you do not tell us what the problem is how can you expect an answer? Are you bothered by the question whether equal things have the same sums? Or by the fact that the number of elements is finite but unspecified?